# Send form data as GET parameters with jsonp and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

Hi Guys I'm new to jsonp. All I'm trying to do is simply send simple form data. I understand you cannot POST using jsonp as it is a standard script GET request. Below I've tried both serialize() or serializeArray() the form data but nothing is included in the GET request, please let me know where I'm going wrong?
HTML:

```
<form class="qd-bd-frm" name="qd-bd-frm" id="qd-bd-frm">
  <input type="hidden" value="9614d609b2b7987d734" name="uid" />
  <p>
    <textarea class="qd-input" placeholder="Your Message" name="msg"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" class="qd-btn" value="Send" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.cross-domain.com/send",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: $("#qd-bd-frm").serializeArray(),
    jsonpCallback: "sent",
    success: function (result)
    {
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    },
    complete: function (xhr, status)
    {
        alert(status);
    },
    error: function ()
    {

    }
 });
```

PHP:

```
public function send()
{
    header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
    echo "sent(".json_encode( $_GET ).");";

    die();
    // example response: sent({"callback":"sent","_":"1425338880075"});
}
```

If you see above, I'm just echoing the response back and in my success function above, none of my form inputs were included. I can also see this if I check the scripts tab in firebug that only 2 parameters were sent to the server. Any ideas what I'm actually missing here?

Comment: `header( "Content-Type: application/json" );` should be `header( "Content-Type: application/javascript" );` — JSONP is not JSON.

Comment: What does the form look like? What is `f`? If two parameters are sent, then which ones and what makes those form fields different from the others? What happens if you submit the form normally (instead of using JavaScript) - do you get the expected data then?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've edited the question to for clarity. I did change to header( "Content-Type: application/javascript" ); still no luck..